# Flutter set transitions for custom routes

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

in our application we implementing custom route navigation and i want to set transition for that, for example, this is our custom route which that work fine without any problem

```
Navigator(
  key: navigatorKey,
  initialRoute: Page.screenDashboard.route,
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    final pageName = settings.name;

    final page = _fragments.keys.firstWhere(
            (element) => describeEnum(element) == pageName);

    return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FadeAndSlideRightTransition(page: _fragments[page]));
  },
),
```

in that how can i set transition for `MaterialPageRoute`?

for example:

```
class SlideRightRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  SlideRightRoute({this.page})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              page,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(animation),
                child: child,
              ),
        );
}
```

this test doesn't work and i get error:

```
return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SlideRightRoute (page: _fragments[page]));
```

**error**

```
error: The return type 'SlideRightRoute ' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context. (return_of_invalid_type_from_closure at [fluttersamples] lib\screens.dart:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

using

```
return SlideRightRoute(page: _fragments[page]);
```

instead of

```
return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _fragments[page]);
```

solved my issue